# MySQL group by and aggregate, how to get the wanted id at the end?

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I have this query

```
SELECT MAX(`sms`.`datetime`) as `datetime`, `sms`.`id_phone`
FROM `user`, `sms`                   
WHERE `user`.`id` = `sms`.`user_id`                   
AND (`user`.`id` = '42')                   
GROUP BY `sms`.`id_phone`
```

How can I get the `id` field corresponding to the returned row?
If I do `SELECT MAX(sms.datetime) as datetime, sms.id_phone, sms.id` it won't give me the id corresponding to the MAX(datetime) row but any id from the group by...

I can't figure that out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tricky way to achieve that by using a *specific?* MySQL feature,
**ORDER BY** in **GROUP_CONCAT** aggregate function like so:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(images.id ORDER BY images.id), -- HERE
    contributions.id 
FROM 
    images 
JOIN 
    contributions 
ON 
    images.object_id = contributions.id 
WHERE 
    (object_type = 1 OR object_type IS NULL) AND place = 1 
GROUP BY 
    contributions.id 
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

This query doesn't answer specifically answer my question because it was too late when I found that. And to do so it has to be changed a little. But it's a good direction to search.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT sms.id from sms
WHERE sms.datetime = 
  SELECT MAX(sms.datetime)
  FROM user, sms                   
  WHERE user.id` = sms.user_id                   
  AND (user.id = 42)
```

Add in the other fields you want, and the group by.

One gotcha is if two rows have the same max datetime. If this is a possibility, and you only want one result, use a LIMIT.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer skip the _group by_ part and I think that's the main problem in my question plus I cant have a subquery as I'm running this on 1.000.000 entries table.
I guess it is just not possible as it is mentioned here: [MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 11.15.3 GROUP BY and HAVING with Hidden Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) Too bad.